# Atheros ar5005g

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, acer-aspire

I have a wireless atheros ar5005g card in my Acer aspire 5040 laptop.My problem is "cannot find network".All other wireless laptops see my network . I have win7 installed with the latest drivers.Any help will be appreciated
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Is the wireless controller enabled?

IIRC Fn + F7 is the key combo to toggle WiFi on/off, should be indicated by an orange LED.

You may have to install the Acer Launch Manager as this will enable the use of the Function Keys and Shortcut Keys on the Keyboard.

Comment: @georgesbou - you're most welcome, feel free to accept the answer as correct by using the check mark icon. :)